# sqlplus not responding after enter password

Tags: oracle12c, centos-6.9

SQLPLUS is not responding after entering the user name and password.

```
[root@ns3369978 ~]# su oracle
bash-4.1$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Dec 27 07:52:53 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: xxxx
Enter password:
```

After entering the password, it is neither connecting nor showing any error. Even I am not able to come out of this. OS is **CentOS release 6.9 (Final)** on my server. How to find and resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched and found one solution. By using the below command I am able to connect oracle.

sqlplus -prelim "system/123lkls as sysdba"